# Consume isn't finished but product is successfully bought

Tags: android

I am using Google Play's Billing API v3.

Start purchase flow.

Press "Buy" button on Google Play dialog.

Quickly killed the application from background.

As result you will see, that product successfully bought, but consume isn't finished.

I want to know that user can do order "cancel" or not after "Buy" button clicked.

How can I handle this state in my application ?